# What are the biggest reasons that Cars get higher Land Speed Records than motorcycles'?

Tags: aerodynamics, rocket-science

What are the biggest reasons that Cars get higher Land Speed Records than motorcycles'?

It is because cars have a more streamlined frame than than motorcycles? But, from pictures, it seems that doesn't matter with LSR vehicles.

Is it because more rocket can be packed onto a car, as compared to a motorbike? Or is it a higher chance of high-speed accidents with motorcycles? Or a limit of current manufacturing ability?

Most likely, it's a combination of those reasons and more... But, what are the main reasons?

Comment: That seems to be a question about *car/motorcycle engineering*.

Comment: @ACuriousMind - Well, I flagged it for a move to Engineering...

Comment: This title makes no sense...

Comment: @Steeven - ... Copy and paste errors...

Comment: None of the above.  Try reading up before asking questions like this.

Comment: Are you kidding, 'this ain't rocket science', see what I did there ;)

Comment: What is your proof that "motorcycles are more aerodynamic than cars"?

Comment: According to the link in @Daniel's answer, some cars are 3 wheels, so it seems like it might be possible to go to 2 wheels (with skids or something for low speeds). I don't quite understand how this would be helpful, though, since it's all about engines and aerodynamics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main phenomena which limit land vehicle speed are aerodynamic drag, lack of stability, and lack of power. Drag increases (approximately) with the frontal area of the vehicle. Stability increases with the weight, length and width of the vehicle. Finally, power increases (approximately) with the volume of the vehicle.

Let's say you keep the shape of the vehicle approximately the same. Then, drag increases as the square of the length, power and weight increase as the cube of the length, and stability increases as some function of the length. In sum, bigger is better.

The wheels are also a problem, with accelerations on the order of [fifty thousand gravities at the treads](http://www.wired.co.uk/news/archive/2014-03/21/bloodhound-ssc-1000mph-car). Centrifugal force is proportional to velocity squared divided by radius, so again, bigger is better.

Finally, it's tough to protect a motorcycle rider when he crashes; you can't make a wrap-around protective tub as you can with a race car.